# The pipe name could not be obtained for the pipe URI: Access is denied

Tags: asp.net, wcf, iis, named-pipes, self-hosting

I am getting an "Access is denied" error on a 2012 R2 server when my web app on that server tries to access a self-hosted WCF service on that server using named pipes.

I do not have this issue on my development machine (Win 7).  I can access the WCF service via the client test app on both the server and my development machine.

If I enable ASP.NET Impersonation on the web site using a user account that has full control permissions to the install folder for the WCF service, then the error goes away.  I do not want to use impersonation since I understand it has significant performance penalties (not to mention security issues) and the WCF service is called for every user input during a session.

The strange thing is... If I set the app pool to run as either the user with rights to the service folder as described above or as a user with admin privileges, then I still get the error if ASP.NET Impersonation is disabled.  The error will go away only after I enable ASP.NET Impersonation on the web site.

I do not have access to the source for the WCF service.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, the web app was located on the D:\ drive and the Anonymous Authentication user (IUSR) did not have RX permissions to the web app location.

Note that if you are using Windows Authentication, then the same issue occurs if the Windows Authenticated user does not have RX permissions to the location of the web app.

The problem was resolved once I gave the authenticated user the proper permission.

Sometimes the solution really is just plain simple...

"Ain't got no gas in it" - Slingblade.